# how to set formauthentication expire time? it not works,expire in 10min

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

hi i used form authentication and create ticket and add it to Response it works good.

when i look at created cookies by Firefox tools>pageinfo>security>cookies find that the expire time set currently on cookies .

it works good on local but when i upload it on server (server 2008-iis7) ,the expire time
not works but sets on cookie and always my cookie expires about 10 minus and member will
log out.
has it some specially settings,i look at some example on internet but cant not find anythings.

my authentication codes:

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
    username,//username
    DateTime.Now,
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
    true,
    rollname,
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath); 

    string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,hashCookies); // Hashed ticket
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120);

      Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

i used this method in global.asax to check requests authentication:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // look if any security information exists for this request
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {

         // see if this user is authenticated, any authenticated cookie (ticket) exists for this user
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                // see if the authentication is done using FormsAuthentication
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
                {

                   // Get the roles stored for this request from the ticket
                    // get the identity of the user
                    FormsIdentity identity = (FormsIdentity)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

                   // get the forms authetication ticket of the user
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = identity.Ticket;

                   // get the roles stored as UserData into the ticket 
                    string[] roles = ticket.UserData.Split(',');

                    // create generic principal and assign it to the current request
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = new  System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

in my web config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms loginUrl="~/Home.aspx" timeout="120" />

</authentication>
```

Comment: Any reason you don't just use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx